# 3d manipulators and hotkeys

Tags: 3d-manipulator

When it comes to scale, rotation, move, there are two display modes:

1. One that doesn't show 3D manipulators
2. One that shows manipulators.

You are in that second mode, say your are in scale mode, with your scale manipulators visible that you are able to grab, it you hit hotkey <kbd>R</kbd> to rotate, you can rotate but it doesn't change the (scale) manipulators to rotation manipulators, to do so you have to click on the button down bellow.

It would be nice that if you hit hotkey <kbd>G</kbd> (move), <kbd>R</kbd> (rotate), <kbd>S</kbd> (scale), it changes the manipulators accordingly. Would this be possible?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think such option exists (unless you'll do some scripting). The solution for you may be making all the *manipulators* visible. Enable all of them clicking on the *manipulators* icons with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd>.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

By default you can use <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Spacebar</kbd> to enable/disable the manipulator widget. If you enable the pie menu addon, the same shortcut brings up a pie menu that allows you to change the manipulator type.

[image: pie menu addon]

As you can see there are several different menus that can be turned on/off so if you only want the manipulator menu you can disable the others. The manipulator option at the top turns the widget on/off.

[image: manipulator pie menu]