# Are there shortcuts for the manipulators (move/scale/rotate) for Blender 2.79

Tags: 3d-manipulator

It seems to me that by now this question would have been asked... many times.

I have searched and found many questions/answers that are close, however, they don't seem to answer this specific question... at least not that I can find.

Are there shortcuts that bring up the move/scale/rotate manipulators? Instead of having to go to the bottom of the screen. I know about G, S, R, but that's not what I'm talking about.

I apologies if I am beating a dead horse, but I can't find an answer.

Thank you,

Jim

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [3d-manipulators and hotkeys](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79928/3d-manipulators-and-hotkeys)

Comment: I followed the link, but that isn't quite it. If you go to the bottom of the screen and select the translate, scale, rotate icons they bring up the appropriate manipulators. I'd rather do this with hotkeys. Is this possible?

Comment: You need to create your own shortcuts. There are no pre-assigned ones.

Comment: Any chance you know of a good tutorial on how to do this? I'm not a noob to modeling software, but I am to Blender :) and Blender seems to be a little more entailed then other software.

Comment: There is a lot of information on this site. Use the search box at the top of the page.